# Why does Xcode 6 boilerplate define SKScene +method in GameViewController.m?

Tags: sprite-kit

Spritekit boiler plate has the following in GameViewController.m

```
#import "GameViewController.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation SKScene (Unarchive)

+ (instancetype)unarchiveFromFile:(NSString *)file {
    /* Retrieve scene file path from the application bundle */
    NSString *nodePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file ofType:@"sks"];
    /* Unarchive the file to an SKScene object */
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:nodePath
                                      options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
                                        error:nil];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *arch = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    [arch setClass:self forClassName:@"SKScene"];
    SKScene *scene = [arch decodeObjectForKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
    [arch finishDecoding];

    return scene;
}

@end
```

I understand the method but what I don't understand is why it is being defined within the GameViewController.m file. GameViewController inherits from UIViewController. Why not place the class extension in GameScene.m?

Answer (score 1):

The category extends `SKScene` and all of its subclasses, including `GameScene`. It makes sense for it to be in the view controller, since that's where the initial scene is loaded and presented. If declared in GameScene.m, you would need to add an appropriate `@interface` to `GameScene.h` to use it without a compiler error. It would make sense to add the category to an `SKScene` subclass that allows users to select a level from a menu, since that subclass would need to load and present the various scenes.

**EDIT:** To unarchive a `.sks` file from a `SKScene` subclass, add the following to your view controller's `.h` file and import the `.h` in your scene subclass.

```
@interface SKScene (Unarchive)

+ (instancetype)unarchiveFromFile:(NSString *)file;

@end
```

Comment: How would you be able to reuse unarchiveFromFile from the view controller or a SKScene subclass? It seems like this is the behaviour that Apple is performing in their WWDC 2014 Session 608 video.